# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'fun'

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to call an function with table type argument which is defined in package scope, but got error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'fun'.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg AS
    TYPE aging_sch_record_type IS
        RECORD (days_delq NUMBER, eligible NUMBER, unit NUMBER, balance NUMBER);
    TYPE aging_sch_table_type IS
        TABLE OF aging_sch_record_type INDEX BY VARCHAR2(20);

    PROCEDURE proc ();
    FUNCTION fun (v_aging_sch_table aging_sch_table_type,
        v_days_delq NUMBER, v_eligible NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
END pkg;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY pkg AS
    PROCEDURE proc () AS
        CURSOR aging_sch_cursor IS
        SELECT ...
        GROUP BY ...;

        v_aging_sch_row aging_sch_cursor%rowtype;
        v_aging_sch_table aging_sch_table_type;
    BEGIN
        FOR v_aging_sch_row IN aging_sch_cursor LOOP
            v_aging_sch_table(v_aging_sch_row.days_delq || ' ' || v_aging_sch_row.eligible).days_delq := v_aging_sch_row.days_delq;
            v_aging_sch_table(v_aging_sch_row.days_delq || ' ' || v_aging_sch_row.eligible).eligible := v_aging_sch_row.eligible;
            v_aging_sch_table(v_aging_sch_row.days_delq || ' ' || v_aging_sch_row.eligible).unit    := v_aging_sch_row.unit;
            v_aging_sch_table(v_aging_sch_row.days_delq || ' ' || v_aging_sch_row.eligible).balance := v_aging_sch_row.balance;
        END LOOP;

        INSERT INTO t
        VALUES (fun(v_aging_sch_table,0,2));
    END proc;

    FUNCTION fun (v_aging_sch_table aging_sch_table_type,
        v_days_delq NUMBER, v_eligible NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
        AS
    BEGIN
        ...
    END fun;
END pkg;
```

Any idea on what the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: On what line is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `associative array` in `SQL` (and you cannot use any array declared in package specification in `SQL` in Oracle versions prior to 12c), but you can store result of the `fun` function into local variable, and then insert that variable into table `t`:

```
PROCEDURE proc () AS
    CURSOR aging_sch_cursor IS
    SELECT ...
    GROUP BY ...;

    v_aging_sch_row aging_sch_cursor%rowtype;
    v_aging_sch_table aging_sch_table_type;
    v_fun number;
BEGIN
    FOR v_aging_sch_row IN aging_sch_cursor LOOP
        v_aging_sch_table(v_aging_sch_row.days_delq || ' ' || v_aging_sch_row.eligible).days_delq := v_aging_sch_row.days_delq;
        v_aging_sch_table(v_aging_sch_row.days_delq || ' ' || v_aging_sch_row.eligible).eligible := v_aging_sch_row.eligible;
        v_aging_sch_table(v_aging_sch_row.days_delq || ' ' || v_aging_sch_row.eligible).unit    := v_aging_sch_row.unit;
        v_aging_sch_table(v_aging_sch_row.days_delq || ' ' || v_aging_sch_row.eligible).balance := v_aging_sch_row.balance;
    END LOOP;

    v_fun := fun(v_aging_sch_table,0,2)
    INSERT INTO t
    VALUES (v_fun);
END proc;
```

Furthermore, you are inserting result of the function into table `t` without naming  column - does that table really have only one column? If not, you should name every column into which you are inserting data, as in:

```
INSERT INTO t (COLUMN1)
VALUES (v_fun);
```

If you weren't indexing by string you could have used standalone object type and nested table which would have worked in SQL, but in your case that is not an option.